# Preventing a registry update based on a condition

Tags: advanced-installer

I have Advanced Installer software version 6.3. In my installer project there is a registry key update in the Registry section of the project.

How do I prevent the registry key update based on a parameter or property? I have attached a pic for reference. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value under the registry key has a corresponding component in the Organization page.

The solution would be to condition all value components from the Organization page using the installer public property.

See the [How to conditionally install a file or a registry?](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-file-registry-condition.html) article for more details.